# Emacs backup automatically disabled for version controlled files

Tags: emacs

For some reason, my emacs does not create backup for version controlled files
Here are settings in my .emacs

```
(defvar backup-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/backup/"))
(defvar autosave-dir (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/autosave/"))
(setq backup-directory-alist (list (cons ".*" backup-dir)))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix autosave-dir)
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,autosave-dir t)))
```

I checked backup for others files (like .emacs itself), It properly created backup for those. But It did not create backup for any version controlled files. 
Can someone tell me how to debug this?

Comment: I tried using http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups, But even that did not backup file

Comment: but that emacswiki link is very helpful in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
(setq vc-make-backup-files t)
```